# Entity Framework 4 maps DateTimeOffset to SQL datetime in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, datetimeoffset

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 RTM with .NET/Entity Framework 4 RTM with a model driven design approach.
When I create an entity with a DateTimeOffset field the EF modeler tries to map the DateTimeOffset to a SQL datetime instead of a SQL datetimeoffset.
I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express so the datetimeoffset is supported in the database.

Visual Studio comes up with this error:

> Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.DateTimeOffset[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=]' of member 'Created' in type 'Data.SqlStorage.MyType' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.datetime[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=3]' of member 'Created' in type 'Data.SqlStorage.Store.MyTypes

If I edit the type directly in the EDMX StorageModels xml section I get the following error:

> Error 40: The Type datetimeoffset is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only PrimitiveTypes can be used without qualification.

Why doesn't the modeler just correctly map this to a SQL datetimeoffset type? 
This problem also occured when I was still working with the beta versions of Visual Studio 2010 & .NET framework 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going the other way (DB->Model). [It worked for Julie Lerman](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/sql-server-2008-data-types-and-entity-framework-4/). It seems to me your manually-edited EDMX should also work if you qualify the `DateTimeOffset` with a namespace.

Comment: The solution was to update from DB once. After that something probably got fixed, because now I can manually change the type to datetimeoffset without VS complaining. Still a bit annoyed I have to manually change it and the modeler doesn't set it correctly itself.

Comment: You can go DB=>Model to see how it's done but I found out that adding the `precision="7"` attribute to the XML fixes this issue.

Answer (score 5):

In the RTM release, you can do something like this in your DbContext:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
     modelBuilder.Entity<EntityName>().Property(p => p.PropertyName).HasColumnType("datetimeoffset");
 }
```

This is also useful for telling Entity Framework Code First to use datetime2 instead of datetime when generating your database.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to update from DB once, AFTER you change manually in the script sql and generated the db. I did it and after I checked my table mapping and the data type was modified to DATE instead of DATETIME. I think the same can be applied if you want to change to DATETIME2.